# Фильтр поиска по значению произвольного поля

Tags: php, wordpress, фильтры

Подскажите, как можно осуществить выбор и вывод постов по значению произвольного поля `gorod`. При этом необходимо, чтобы список имеющихся значений в фильтре выбирался из базы, а не определялся в фильтре вручную.

Спасибо!

```
<label>Город</label>
            <select name="gorod">
    <option value="">Выберите год</option>
    <?php
    $metakey = 'gorod';
    $gorod = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );
     if ($gorod) {
    foreach ($gorod as $gorod) {
        echo "<option value=\"" . $gorod . "\">" . $gorod . "</option>";
    }
  }
    ?>
</select>
```

фильтр выводится, работает, но  при условии, если комментирую строку

```
//$gorod = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );
```

Фильтрация по значению полей `gorod` не осуществляется ни при каком варианте.

```
/*код фильтра целиком*/

add_shortcode('mytask_filter_iv', 'get_freelance_task_filter_iv');
function get_freelance_task_filter_iv(){ ?>

    <form action="/customsearch/" method="get">
         <div id="searchorders">
        <div class="search-block">
                    <label>Искать задания со словом</label>
                    <input type="text" class="search-input long-input" name="word" value="<?php echo $_GET['word']; ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="search-block">
            <label>Город</label>
            <select name="gorod">
    <option value="">Выберите год</option>
    <?php
    $metakey = 'gorod';
    //$gorod = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );
     if ($gorod) {
    foreach ($gorod as $gorod) {
        echo "<option value=\"" . $gorod . "\">" . $gorod . "</option>";
    }
  }
    ?>
</select>
</div>
            <div class="search-block">
                    <label>Категория заданий</label>
                    <?php
                    $catargs = array(
                            'number'        => 0
                            ,'offset'       => 0
                            ,'orderby'      => 'name'
                            ,'order'        => 'ASC'
                            ,'hide_empty'   => false
                            ,'fields'       => 'all'
                            ,'slug'         => ''
                            ,'hierarchical' => true
                            ,'name__like'   => ''
                            ,'pad_counts'   => false
                            ,'get'          => ''
                            ,'child_of'     => 0
                            ,'parent'       => ''
                    );
                    $ordercat = get_terms('task-subject', $catargs);

                    $cat_list = (isset($_GET['cats'])&&$_GET['cats'][0][0])? get_terms( 'task-subject', array('include'=>$_GET['cats'][0][0]) ): '';

                    $sel = new Rcl_List_Terms();
                    echo $sel->get_select_list($ordercat,$cat_list,1,0,'select',true);
                    ?>
            </div>
            <div class="search-block">
            <label>Укажите категорию:</label>
<select class="search-input long-input" name="vibor">
<option value="">Выберете</option>
<option value="Заказ">Заказ</option>
<option value="Предложение">Предложение</option>
</select>
 </div>
            <div class="search-block">
                <label>Заданий на страницу</label>
                <select class="search-input long-input" name="num">
                <option value="10">10 заданий</option>
                <option <?php selected(20,$_GET['num']); ?> value="20">20 заданий</option>
                <option <?php selected(30,$_GET['num']); ?> value="30">30 заданий</option>
                <option <?php selected('-1',$_GET['num']); ?> value="-1">Все задания</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="search-block">
                <label>Статус заданий</label>
                <select class="search-input long-input" name="status">
                <option <?php selected(1,$_GET['status']); ?> value="1">Открытые</option>
                <option <?php selected(2,$_GET['status']); ?> value="2">В работе</option>
                <option <?php selected(3,$_GET['status']); ?> value="3">Закрытые</option>
                </select>
            </div>
           <div class="search-block">
                <label>Сортировка по</label>
                <select class="search-input long-input" name="orderby">
                <option <?php selected('date',$_GET['orderby']); ?> value="date">дате добавления</option>
                <option <?php selected('title',$_GET['orderby']); ?> value="title">заголовку</option>
                <option <?php selected('meta_value_num',$_GET['orderby']); ?> value="meta_value_num">стоимости</option>
                </select>
            </div> 
            <div class="search-block">
                <label>Диапазон бюджета</label>
                от <input class="search-input long-input" type="number" name="min-price" size="5" value="<?php echo $_GET['min-price']; ?>"> 
                до <input class="search-input long-input" type="number" name="max-price" size="5" value="<?php echo $_GET['max-price']; ?>">
            </div>   
            <div class="search-block">
                <input type="submit" class="recall-button" value="Показать задания">
            </div>


        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_key" value="byudzhet_82">
    </form>

    <?php
 if($_GET['num']){

            if(!$_GET['min-price']) $_GET['min-price'] = 0;
            if(!$_GET['max-price']) $_GET['max-price'] = 99999999;

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'task',
                'meta_key' => $_GET['meta_key'],
                'posts_per_page' => $_GET['num'],
                'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
                'order' => $_GET['order'],
                'orderby' => $_GET['orderby'],
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => 'byudzhet_82',
                        'value' => array( $_GET['min-price'], $_GET['max-price'] ),
                        'type' => 'numeric',
                        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                    )
                )
            );
            if ($_GET['vibor']) $args['meta_query'][] = array( 
            'key' => 'vibor', 
            'value' => $_GET['vibor'],
            );

            if($_GET['word']) $args['s'] = $_GET['word'];
            if($_GET['cats'][0][0]) $args['tax_query'] = array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'task-subject',
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => $_GET['cats'][0]
                        )
                    );

            if($_GET['status']) $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                                'key' => 'step_order',
                                'value' => $_GET['status'],
                                'type' => 'numeric',
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                            );


            query_posts( $args );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема, как минимум, в том, что в начале функции нет строки

```
global $wpdb;
```

Comment: Да, это решило проблему. Спасибо за помощь.